# .d.ts not compiling after TypeScript 2.6.1

Tags: typescript

I was using TypeScript version 2.5 with this ambient module for `suncalc` package:

```
// Note: incomplete
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/suncalc

declare module "suncalc" {
  interface suncalcResult {
    solarNoon: Date;
    nadir: Date;
    sunrise: Date;
    sunset: Date;
    sunriseEnd: Date;
    sunsetStart: Date;
    dawn: Date;
    dusk: Date;
    nauticalDawn: Date;
    nauticalDusk: Date;
    nightEnd: Date;
    night: Date;
    goldenHourEnd: Date;
    goldenHour: Date;
  }

  function sunCalc(date: Date, latitude: number, longitude: number): suncalcResult;

  export = { // COMPLAINING HERE <--------------------------- line 24
    getTimes: sunCalc
  };
}
```

In TypeScript 2.5, I got this file called `suncalc.d.ts` and compiled with no error. When I upgraded to 2.6, it started to blame:

```
message: 'The expression of an export assignment must be an identifier or qualified name in an ambient context.'
at: '24,12'
source: 'ts'
```

However, in the [changelog of TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript) there is nothing about changes in ambient modules.

Why is not compiling now? How should I write the export in TS2.6?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is mentioned on the [breaking changes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#arbitrary-expressions-are-forbidden-in-export-assignments-in-ambient-contexts) page. Export assignments like the one in question are executable code, and 2.6.1 was made [more strict in enforcing general rule that executable code is not allowed in declaration files](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17991).

The suggested way to rewrite the declaration is to declare a variable with explicit type and export the variable:

```
const _exported: { getTimes: sunCalc };
export = _exported;
```

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/types/index.d.ts You can see an example here.